# iOS Images for iPhone and iPad and Rotation of Images

Tags: ios5, rotation

I read on the apple website that when you choose images to display say for a background image it has to be of certain quality. See [this link](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/IconsImages/IconsImages.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH14-SW2).

I am developing an app for iOS 5 with XCode 4.3.2.

1. How do I know if my device is a high-resolution one?
2. For setting a background image, when you do rotations of a device say left or right, do you need to include a much wider version of that image? I am doing a header and setting it as my background with a name "My Apple App" in the background. Do I need to make a wider version so it can stretch?